# Android Location of touch in picture

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

I'm new to Android Programming and have a big problem.

I am zooming a picture and scroll it. Then the user have to touch a point. How do I get the touched point in dependency of the zoomed picture? (`x`& `y` values starting from the left top corner of the image.)

Zooming and scrolling is working.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             myImageView.mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
             myImageView.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            if (myImageView.state == NONE || myImageView.state == DRAG
                    || myImageView.state == FLING) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    if (myImageView.fling != null)
                        myImageView.fling.cancelFling();
                    myImageView.setState(DRAG);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (myImageView.state == DRAG) {
                        deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        fixTransX = myImageView.getFixDragTrans(deltaX,
                                myImageView.viewWidth,
                                myImageView.getImageWidth());
                        fixTransY = myImageView.getFixDragTrans(deltaY,
                                myImageView.viewHeight,
                                myImageView.getImageHeight());
                        myImageView.matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX,
                                fixTransY);
                        myImageView.fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    myImageView.setState(NONE);
                    break;
                }
```

I am using the `TouchImageView` from Michael Ortiz. Find it here on [Github](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java).

I need a method similar to `CGPoint pos = [recognizer locationInView: map]` in Objective C (iPhone SDK)

br Stone

Comment: how are you "zooming" the picture? My app does something similar: the user selects a picture and crops it and I work on the resulting image, which could be just displayed or even saved to a file. But I do it with the zooming tools which are available on most Android devices...

Comment: @DigCamara: i have added the code to the original post. The zoomed picture is just displayed.

Comment: a brief look at the code tells me that you should probably look into using the transformCoordTouchToBitmap method to obtain the correct coordinates. Being unfamiliar with the library, I can't really say if this will help you, though.

Comment: i have already tried it with this method, but i need one where i get always the same coordinats of a touched point in the image...no matter if the image is zoomed in, zoomed out, scrolled or something else